# Nested For Loop Teething Issues when naming showdetail sheets from a pivot table

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code that does three things...

1. ShowsDetails of all pivot table row labels for each row `c`
2. Names the sheets containing the show details data on row label. for each long `x`
3. As some of the row labels are more than 30 characters - it uses an `if` function to check whether the row label contains 30 characters and subsequently cuts it down so that the row label name can fit.

I am however having some teething issues... after showing the details of the first row label it subsequently names the first sheet all the names of the sheet. I have obviously got my loops mixed up but im not sure where I am going wrong. Could someone advise? thank you.

```
Sub test()

Dim PivotSheet As Worksheet
Set PivotSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Pivot Table")

 Dim c As Range, x As Long, lastrow As Long
 lastrow = PivotSheet.cells.Find("*", cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row
 
    With PivotSheet.PivotTables(1)
        For Each c In .DataBodyRange.Resize(, 1)
            c.ShowDetail = True ' shows details of pivot table row labels
           For x = 6 To lastrow - 1
           If Len(PivotSheet.cells(x, 1)) > 31 Then 
           ActiveSheet.Name = Left(PivotSheet.cells(x, 1), 30) ' names spreadsheet containing pivottable details depending on row label
           Else
          ActiveSheet.Name = PivotSheet.cells(x, 1)
         End If
          Next x
          Next c
        ActiveSheet.Move After:=Sheets(12)
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems like the `x` loop should not be nested inside the `c` loop

Comment: @TimWilliams yeah I get that impression as well, im just not quite sure how to get the code right. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need the inner loop (assuming the sheet label is coming from the same row as `c` and the first column of the sheet)

```vb
Sub test()

    Dim PivotSheet As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Dim c As Range, x As Long, lastrow As Long
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set PivotSheet = wb.Worksheets("Pivot Table")

    lastrow = PivotSheet.Cells.Find("*", PivotSheet.Cells(1, 1), _
                  xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row
 
    For Each c In PivotSheet.PivotTables(1).DataBodyRange.Columns(1).Cells
       c.ShowDetail = True   ' shows details of pivot table row labels
       Set ws = ActiveSheet  'get a reference to the new sheet
       ws.Name = Left(c.EntireRow.Cells(1).Value, 30) 'no need for a test here...
       ws.Move After:=wb.Sheets(12)
    Next c
    
End Sub
```